# Collision between camera and objects in A-Frame

Tags: three.js, aframe

I've been trying to develop a VR experience using aframe on google cardboard. The player in this game will get point deduction and knock-back when collide with vehicle (car1). Initially I tried to apply static-body and dynamic-body and define the script when collide occurs. However, it's not working as intended.

I'm out of ideas and really don't understand why I cant get the knock-back.

Need some help from A-Frame experts and developers

Thanks in advance!

```
        <a-scene stats physics="debug:true;
        <a-entity id='player' camera="active: true" look-controls wasd-controls 
        data-aframe-default-camera static-body>
        <a-text id="score" value="Score" position="-0.2 -0.5 -1" color="black" width="5" anchor="left"></a-text>
        </a-entity>

        <a-entity id='car1' obj-model="obj:#car_obj;mtl:#car_mtl" dynamic-body></a-entity>
        </a-scene>

        <script>
        let score = 0;
        let hit = false
        const knockback= () => {
          clearTimeout(resetId)
          $("#player").body.position.set(0, 0.6,-4)
          $("#player").body.velocity.set(0, 5,0)
          $("#player").body.angularVelocity.set(0, 0,0)
          hit = false
        }

        on($("#player"), 'collide', (e) => {
          const car1 =$("#car1")

          if (e.detail.body.id == car1.body.id){
            hit = true
            score = score + 1
            $("#score").setAttribute('text','value','Score '+score)

          }
        })
      </script>
```

Comment: Where is the method called ?

Comment: I'm new to aframe. I'm not sure how to call the method...